# Oracle & SQL Server Dataset comparison

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

I am trying to do a C# dataset caparison between two datasets from two different DB's. Dataset one is from Oracle and Dataset two is from SQL Server and I'm comparing these datasets after an ETL jobs runs to move data from Oracle to SQL Server to validate the results. Problem I'm having is that the data in SQL Server matches but the Dates are in a different format from source to destination and also decimal point rounding.

Has anyone got a good way to circumvent this problem. I was thinking about changing my queries from the source and destination tables that fill the Dataset to format the dates etc... so the comparison would be easier but I wanted to see was there any other way?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151817.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I am doing a dataset to dataset comparison and dont actually need to do anything with the datasets other than fill them and then do a compare so I am not looking to map them other than a validation check of the ETL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the date formats set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT environment variable to the desired format. This assumes that you catch the data in a string. Oracle will format the date to the format you specified. For the decimal point rounding I don't get it. Those numbers should be the same. In case you get a decimal point and want a comma, use NLS_MUMERIC_CHARACTERS 'DG' to choose which character to use a Decimal point or Group separator.

For example '.,' selects a '.' for decimal point and a comma for group separator.

The environment variables can be set from the clients OS and also from within the Oracle session. To do this, issue `alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS';` or whatever format suits you best.

Comment: Thanks mate, I connecting to Oracle from a Windows Box and then doing my C# comparison on this machine with two data sources for Oracle and SQL Server. Can I set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT environment variable on a Windows machine or is this Unix specific? I dont have access to the physical Oracle machine to change any config?

Comment: Hi, you can also do this on your client, no problem. It can even be done from within the session: alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyymmddhh24miss', if you want to do so. I edit the answer for this.